# How to obtain a list of python apps installed on a Windows HDD if the dis doesn't boot

Tags: list

Is there a way to obtain a list of python apps installed on a Windows HDD if the dis doesn't boot.  I know you can do this with Python if the OS boots, but I had to pull out my hard drive to get the data and want to know if I can get a list or where I can see what python apps are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE (Name LIKE 'Python%')" | Select-Object Name, Version
```

so i would put HDD into an external hard drive housing or docking station and access it from a working PC it should automatically assign the external HDD with a drive letter. Once you have this letter assume 'S' then powershell script would be $driveLetter = "S:"

```
# Get list of installed apps on the specified drive
$installedApps = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product 
WHERE InstallLocation LIKE '$($driveLetter)%'"

# Display the list of installed apps
foreach ($app in $installedApps) {
Write-Host "Name: $($app.Name), Version: $($app.Version)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick resposne!  So, if for example, my OS drive that is not booting is "S:" drive this wouldn't be an issue?  If possible, could you dummy it down a little more?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).